# Filesystem infinite loop

Tags: files, directory, file-copy

So I accidentially created an infinite loop by copying a parent folder into the current one and now it loops infinitely.

Is it safe to delete the folder?

Or how do I delete the looping directory safely without deleting everything else?

I used the cp command like this `cp -r /somefolder/* /somefolder/subfolder/` and didn't realise it would create a loop before I hit enter.

Comment: this should relatively stop by itself, files systems have limits... you should probably kill that cp in time, this potentially takes a permanent toll on the performance of your file system

Comment: i already stopped it (it didn't ran for long and just completed), so it's not infinite? I just didn't go to the end?

Comment: it is copy, not move, so the original files should still be there, with the added copies of those files

Comment: Which implementation of `cp` are you using? Some (most?) implementations detect an attempt to copy a directory into itself. E.g., with GNU `cp`, `$ mkdir a a/b && cp -r a/* a/b/` gives `cp: cannot copy a directory, 'a/b', into itself, 'a/b/b'`. It does indeed create a copy of the tree rooted in `b` into `b` itself, but it does not keep reading and copying the already copied stuff (as in `a/b` → `a/b/b` → `a/b/b/b` → `a/b/b/b/b`  → ...)